# Apply filter on a comma seperated object column and also on another column

Tags: angularjs

I'm facing a problem when I try to apply filters on multiple columns in an object. I need to apply these filters basing on the drop-down selected: one drop-down is directly linked to the id while another value holds the name but has to be filtered based on the list column. Suppose if selected def it should display

```
1 def
2 ghi
```

My data will be

```
$scope.items =[
{ id: 1, list: ['abc','cde'], name: 'abc'},
{ id: 2, list: ['def','abc'], name: 'def'},
{ id: 3, list: ['def','ghi'], name: 'ghi'},
];
```

my html code is

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items| filter:searchText">
{{item.id}} {{item.name}}
</tr>
```

Since filters have to be applied when the user clicks the button, they are written under the submit function; here's my filter code in the controller:

```
$scope.filtr = {};
//$scope.filtr.id & $scope.filtr.list are the filters hold the value of drop-downs
$scope.submit = function() {
  for(prop in $scope.filtr) {
    $scope.searchText[prop] = $scope.filtr[prop];
  }
}
```

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: @Omar Einea not getting the exact data after applying filters if chosen def i should get two records but getting one record only

Comment: write it as `ng-repeat="item in filtr = (items| filter:searchText)"`, then you can access `$scope.filtr` and loop over it

Comment: @Aleksey Solovey Tried with your update but data is not been loaded to UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create `custom` filter:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.searchText = {};
  $scope.items = [
    { id: 1, list: ['abc', 'cde'], name: 'abc' },
    { id: 2, list: ['def', 'abc'], name: 'def' },
    { id: 3, list: ['def', 'ghi'], name: 'ghi' }
  ];
  $scope.visibleItems = $scope.items;
  $scope.FilterArray = function(){    
    function normilize(x){
      return (x + '').toLowerCase();
    }  
    $scope.visibleItems = $scope.items.filter(function(x) {                      
      for(var prop in $scope.searchText){
        var searchVal = normilize($scope.searchText[prop]);
        if(Array.isArray(x[prop])) {
          if(!x[prop].some(x => normilize(x).indexOf(searchVal) != -1))
            return false;
        }
        else{
          var originVal = normilize(x[prop]);                        
          if(originVal.indexOf(searchVal) === -1)
            return false;
        }                                
      }
      return true;
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
  list: <input type='text' ng-model='searchText.list'/>  
  name: <input type='text' ng-model='searchText.name'/>
  <button ng-click='FilterArray()'>Apply filters</button>
  <ul >  
    <li ng-repeat="item in visibleItems">
      {{item}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot use custom directive for filter in the scope right now. So need to implement the logic in the controller and filters has to be applied on submit of the button